# TestFlight build produces bad push tokens

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

What could be the cause of bad push tokens generated by the builds when they're downloaded from the TestFlight?

Is it the **Automatic Code Signing** that signs the RELEASE using `Apple Development`certificate instead of `Apple Distribution`? But I've been doing that in several projects without any issues at all.

---

**Sample bad push token generated by TestFlight build:**

```
7F0000000000000020000061A24474DD290000000000000000000000028359F6
```

**Sample good push token generated by build from Xcode (BOTH with DEBUG and RELEASE run configuration):**

```
83BBE6AFED8323C0A19006C6DE4E6BF481D8A5AE3A1372EFEA84DDF71BA5C6F0
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sharing here my solution. For more context, the project is written in Objective-C.

I also have tried uploading builds to TestFlight with manual code signing.

The way I convert `NSData` pushToken to `NSString` is using my ever working Swift function and port it to Objective-C:

```
import Foundation

extension NSData {
    @objc func extractPushToken() -> String {
        return self.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
    }
}
```

---

That Swift function works well in both debug and release mode with Swift projects, and it also works with debug mode in my current Objective-C project. Seems weird.

But the only solution that I have to make the TestFlight build (release mode) work is to use Objective-C way of extracting the pushToken:

```
- (NSString *)tokenFromData:(NSData *)tokenData
{
    const unsigned *tokenBytes = [tokenData bytes];
    NSString *tkn = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x %08x",
    ntohl(tokenBytes[0]), ntohl(tokenBytes[1]), ntohl(tokenBytes[2]),
    ntohl(tokenBytes[3]), ntohl(tokenBytes[4]), ntohl(tokenBytes[5]),
    ntohl(tokenBytes[6]), ntohl(tokenBytes[7])];
    
    return [tkn stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
}
```